# PHP Registration Form not processing AJAX data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I may be being stupid, but I am trying to process a registration form using an AJAX call to a PHP page. My PHP page is working perfectly on it's own, but when I try to post the form data to the PHP page through AJAX nothing happens.

This is my AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {    

$("#register").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
                $("#message").html('');
                var values = $(this).serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "http://cs11ke.icsnewmedia.net/DVPrototype/external-data/register.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: values,
                    success: function (data) {
                    $("#message").html(data);
                    }
                    });
                }); 

});
```

This is the form:

```
<div id="registerform">
    <form method='post' id='register'>
        <h3>Register</h3>
        <p>Fill in your chosen details below to register for an account</p>
        <p>Username: <input type='text' name='username' value='' /><br />
           Password: <input type='password' name='password' ><br />
           Repeat Password: <input type='password' name='repeatpassword'></p>
           <input name='submit' type='submit'  value='Register' >
           <input name='reset' type='reset' value='Reset'><br /><br />
     </form>      
           <div id="message"></div>                          
</div>
```

And this is my PHP page:

```
<?php function clean_string($db_server = null, $string){
        $string = trim($string);
        $string = utf8_decode($string);
        $string = str_replace("#", "&#35", $string);
        $string = str_replace("%", "&#37", $string);
        if (mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, $string)) {
            $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, $string);
        }
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $string = stripslashes($string);
        }
        return htmlentities($string);
    }

    function salt($string){
        $salt1 = 'by*';
        $salt2 = 'k/z';
        $salted = md5("$salt1$string$salt2");
        return $salted;
    }
?>

<?php
//form data                             
$submit = trim($_POST['submit']);
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);
$repeatpassword = trim($_POST['repeatpassword']);
// create variables
$message = '';
$s_username = '';

    //connect to database
```

{databaseconnection}

```
    $db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
    $db_status = "connected";
    if(!$db_server){

        //error message
        $message = "Error: could not connect to the database.";
    }else{
        $submit = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['submit']);
        $username = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['username']);
        $password = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['password']);
        $repeatpassword = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['repeatpassword']);

                //check all details are entered
                if ($username&&$password&&$repeatpassword){

                    //check password and repeat match
                    if ($password==$repeatpassword){

                        //check username is correct length
                        if (strlen($username)>25) {
                            $message = "Username is too long, please try again.";                           
                        }else{
                            if (strlen($password)>25||strlen($password)<6) {

                                //check password is correct length
                                $message = "Password must be 6-25 characters long, please try again.";                              
                            }else{
                                mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);

                                // check whether username exists
                                $query="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
                                $result= mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
                                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    $message = "Username already exists. Please try again.";
                                }else{

                                    //insert password
                                    $password = salt($password);
                                    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')";
                                    mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Registration failed. ". 
                                    mysqli_error($db_server));
                                    $message = "Registration successful!";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        $message = "Both password fields must match, please try again.";
                    }
                }else{
                    $message = "You must fill in all fields, please try again.";    
                }
            }   

echo $message;          
mysqli_close($db_server);

?>
```

Apologies for all the code. I feel I may be making a stupid mistake but I don't know why the data isn't being posted or returned.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please modify your above PHP code and remove the database credentials (and better change them asap because you just published your database settings on the net)! Same applies to the salt you use for encryption.

Comment: Thanks, what an idiot.

Comment: @kathryn: is register.php the same orgin? Or are you testing using localhost? Plus are you using any php framework?

Comment: @Kathryn, is your request get raised

Comment: Some more words of advice, not relevant for your initial question: your `clean_string()` function will always return a string and never boolean so the condition `if ($username&&$password&&$repeatpassword){` will always be met.

Comment: I have checked your site. Its showing js error on console. these error i got . ReferenceError: event is not defined TypeError: k[0] is undefined

Comment: As @madi wrote above.. Is this a Cross Domain Request? If it is then you can't do a POST.

Comment: @madi it is in the same origin yes! this is from the page registertest.html and I'm trying to call /external-data/register.php

Comment: If it is in the same orgin, why do u have to put url "http://cs11ke.icsnewmedia.net/DVPrototype/external-data/register.php"

Can't you use:
"external-data/register.php"

If the the folder structure

Comment: @madi because I'm building it in HTML so that I can wrap it up using phonegap build, so I have to have the files hosted rather than locally

Answer (score 0):

**Notice: This is more a comment than an answer but this is more readable since it includes code.**

**== EDIT ==**

I Checked your code on http://cs11ke.icsnewmedia.net/DVPrototype/#registerlogin, your form doesn't have a id assigned to it

First: use your console...do you see an XMLHTTPREQUEST in your console?
What are the responses/headers etc? I can't stress this enough: use your console and report back here!!!

Next up the overly complicated ajax call...dumb it down to:

```
$('#register').submit(function(){
    $('#message').html('');

    $.post("http://cs11ke.icsnewmedia.net/DVPrototype/external-data/register.php",
        $(this).serialize(),
        function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $('#message').html(response);
        }
    );

    return false;
});
```

In your PHP put this on top to check whether anything at all came through:

```
die(json_encode($_POST));
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm just trying to get it to work on http://cs11ke.icsnewmedia.net/DVProtoype/registertest.html first, #registerlogin is a different page

Answer (score 0):

Please use Firebug or any other tool, to checḱ if the AJAX-script is called, what is its answer and if there are any errors in the script

Answer (score -1):

My form is not submitting data to my database.
This is the PHP code:

```
<?php require 'core.inc.php'; ?>
<?php require 'connection.inc.php'; ?>
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && 
    isset($_POST['password_again']) && isset($_POST['firstname']) && 
    isset($_POST['surname'])){

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $hashed_password = sha1($password);
  $password_again = sha1('password again');
  $username = $_POST['firstname'];
  $password = $_POST['surname'];

  //check if all fields have been filled
  if(!empty($username)&& !empty($password) && !empty($password_again) && 
      !empty($firstname)&& !empty($surname)){

    if($password != $password_again){
      echo 'Passwords do not match.';
    } else {    
      //check if user is already registered;
      $query = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = {$username} ";
      $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

      if (mysqli_num_rows ($query_run)==1){

        echo 'User Name '.$username.' already exists.';
      } else {
        //register user
        $query = "INSERT INTO `user` VALUES ('', '".$username."', 
        '".$password_hashed."','".$firstname."','".$surname."',)";

      }

      if($query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query)){
        header('Location: reg_succed.php');
      } else {
        echo 'Sorry we couldn\'t register you at this time. try again later';
      }
    }

  }

} else {
  echo 'All fields are required';
}   

?>

<h2>Create New User</h2>

<form id="form" action="<?php echo $current_file ?>" method="POST">
<fieldset title="Login details" id="frame"> 
<legend>USER LOGIN DETAILS</legend>
<label>User Name:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name = "username" id = "username" value="<?php if(isset($username)){ echo $username; } ?>"  maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter your Username" required/><br/>

<label>First Name:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id = "firstname" value="<?php if(isset($firstname)){ echo $firstname;} ?>" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter your Firstname" required/><br/>                    
<label>Surname:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="<?php if(isset($surname)) {echo $surname;} ?>" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter your Surname" required/><br/>

<label>Password:</label><br/>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"   maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter your Password" required/><br/>

<label>Password Again:</label><br/>
<input type="password" name="password_again" id="password again"  maxlength="50"  placeholder="Enter your Password" required/><br/>

<input type="submit" name = "register" id = "register" value="Register">
</fieldset>
</form>

connection code
<?php
require_once("constants.php");

// 1. Create a database connection
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}

// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));

}
?>

core.inc.php code
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$current_file = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

if(isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
$http_referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}



?>
```